# 3 Functions 1 input

Tags: javascript, html

I made a search box that should open and close when searched "button"(input) it's pressed. The problem is that when I want to close the search box I have to click twice and in the Same Spot(x,y axes must be exacly the same else the function submits the result).

```js
function slideOpen(elopen){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elopen);
    elem.style.transition = "width 1.4s ease-in-out"
    elem.style.width = "250px";
    elem.style.height = "50px";
}
    
function slideClosed(elclose){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elclose)
    elem.style.transition = "width 1.4s ease-in-out"
    elem.style.width = "0px";
    elem.style.height = "50px"; 
    elem.style.border = "0";
    elem.style.padding = "10px 25px 10px 25px";
    
}
    
function searchbutton(){
    var typetext = document.getElementById("typetext");
    var typetextWidth = document.getElementById("typetext").getAttribute("width");
    var onClick = document.getElementById("searchtext").onclick; 
    if(typetextWidth === "0"){
    onClick = slideOpen('typetext');
    
    } else {
    onClick = slideClosed('typetext');
    }
         
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input id="typetext" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Patience is a virtue" />
     <input id="searchtext" type="image" src="search.png" onclick="searchbutton()"  />
      
    </form>
```

Comment: *"(x,y axes must be exacly the same else the function submits the result"* Not even one pixel off? Do you have any idea how hard that is?

Comment: Okay, you've said what you want to do. What *specific* problem are you having doing it?

Comment: I wana close the search box from 1 click not two clicks. Or explain to me why does it act like that, why do you have to press twice in the same place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a problem with global variables then I think this is better:

```
...
var searchIsShown = false;

function searchbutton(){

    if(searchIsShown)
    {
        searchIsShown = false;
        slideOpen('typetext');
    } else {
        searchIsShown = true;
        slideClosed('typetext');
    }

}
```

Plus, you should move your `height` and `transition` to CSS